# Simplify Xpath list selection with condition

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

We have a list of divX in HTML code :

```
DivX
    Div
        Div1
            img
        Div2
            Div1
                Div
                    Div text()=Pseudo
            Div2
                Div
                    Divtext()=name
        Div3
            Button
                Span text()=Activate
```

And we need to clic on Activate where the Pseudo = "hello". Here is the long answer I have coded :

```
find element by xpath (span[text()=Activate]/parent::button/parent::div/parent::div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[text()=pseudo]/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div/div[3]/button/span).clic()
```

Is there a simpler way to do it ? By escaping to write so many time "parent" ?

Comment: Please edit your question with properly formatted html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//div[text()='pseudo']//following::span[text()='Activate']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//span[.='Activate'][preceding::div[.='hello']]").click()
```

I don't understand your complicated XPath expression, but if you want to replace multiple `parent` axis, use `ancestor`. It will look like :

```
//span[text()="Activate"]/ancestor::div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[text()="hello"]/ancestor::div[4]/div[3]/button/span
```